# Draw a formative plot?

Tags: r, plot

[image]I have a table as below.I want to have a plot that I can show the point column located between start and end point.  For example I like to show point column by a line in a plot.

```
    point  start.point   end.point
 1    10            20     30
```

Comment: Can you show a sample plot?

Comment: I added a plot. I like this plot (However this one is not a correct plot). but I want a plot that show point in a line and in X axis show start and end point.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to plot a single point on that vertical line?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df <- data.frame(point = c(10,20,30,40,50), start = c(20,30,40,50,60), end = c(30,40,50,60,70))
df.long <- melt(df, id = "point", measure = c("start","end"))
pl <- ggplot(data = df.long, aes(x = point, y = value, group = point)) + geom_line()
pl
```